# Is it possible to circumvent a require statement if the ordering of the requirements are incorrect?

Tags: solidity, tokens, security, reentrant-attacks

Please take the following hypothetical code as an example

```
mapping (address => uint256) public accountBalance;

function deposit(uint256 amount) public {
    accountBalance[msg.sender] = accountBalance[msg.sender].add(amount);
    require(daiToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount));
}
```

I have been informed that this code would be vulnerable to a re-entrancy attack and should instead be written as follows:

```
mapping (address => uint256) public accountBalance;

function deposit(uint256 amount) public {
    require(daiToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount));
    accountBalance[msg.sender] = accountBalance[msg.sender].add(amount);
}
```

How is it possible to cause a state update to the local contract if there is a require statement wrapped around the transferFrom function?

Kindest Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If daiToken were a malicious contract once you have invoked transferFrom then it can call your deposit function before it has finished executing the first time so potentially amount is credited multiple times.

But to be honest ERC20 doesn't guarantee even if you call transferFrom successfully that the transfer of tokens will be OK. You have to trust that it will behave correctly.

Comment: Thanks, could you possibly elaborate on how an ERC20 token's transferFrom function could return true without actually being a successful transfer (assuming an ERC20 implementation such as OpenZepplin's)?

Comment: I do still wonder, though, even if daiToken was malicious, and if it called back into the deposit function from the daiToken contract, how would the accountBalance ever be incorrectly incremented if the "require(daiToken.transferFrom(...))" in the following line fails? Or is the idea that the danger here is simply that the deposit function ends up depositing more user funds than initially intended?

Comment: @Jay OpenZeppelin's implementation obviously do the right thing (tm). An arbitrary implementation can just fire a `Transfer` event and return true, it is a valid ERC20 token because it follows the specification. In general when a contracts calls another, for example at `daiToken.transferFrom()` it is passing the control flow to daiToken and that contract can do anything.

Comment: @Jay The danger is that your contract will be in an temporary inconsistent state, user balance in your contract has increased but tokens aren't in your contract yet. So temporarily the user has its own tokens, and your contract think it has deposited the tokens there. By itself this is not enough to exploit the contract but it is a ticking bomb, together with another failure it might be exploitable.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that the idea is to essentially get the function calls which could possibly reenter "out of the way", so that we can rely on a local stream of adaptations until the end of the lifecycle of the function?

Comment: @Jay Honestly I don't know if there's a good answer. Solidity allows to write unsafe code very easily. Swapping two lines in your example will fix it, but it is hard to recognize that type of errors even for experienced developers. There some research about using formal frameworks to proof that a contract is secure by design, but they are advances in academia not ready for everyone to use them.

Answer (score 1):

There is reentrancy example code you can try out here: https://github.com/KevinSmall/SolidityContractVulnerabilities#reentrancy